# The sound is low compared to windows

Tags: settings, sound

I tried several distros, but for some reason, the sound is low even when I allow the sound to be more than 100%, which is not good because it ruins the quality of the sound. The sound is good on windows, but I don't know what's the problem with Linux exactly. Can I get the same sound as windows on Linux?